# Find the minimum integer r such that $(10^r - 1)/37$ is an integer

Tags: equation-solving, functions, number-theory

I know `Element[(10^r - 1)/37, Integers]` tests the condition.

So what is the command that gives me the minimum integer value `r` such that the condition is true?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let us try to produce the solution without applying brute force, similar to [mgamer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19726/mgamer)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69813/) (that did not actually use *Mathematica*).

```
Reduce[Mod[10^r - 1, 37] == 0, r, Integers]
(* -> C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0 && r == 3 C[1] *)
```

We see that the value of `r` can in fact be any nonnegative multiple of 3. The result sought is then obvious by inspection.

Supposing that we are not willing even to allow for a little interpretation of the above result, or if the outcome is somewhat more complicated, and we want *Mathematica* to produce the answer directly. Then, we can use `Minimize` (note that this finds a global optimum symbolically, and so is different from both `NMinimize` and `FindMinimum`) on the (minimally rearranged) output of `Reduce` to find the value of the undetermined constant:

```
Minimize[{3 C[1], C[1] >= 0}, C[1], Integers]
(* -> {0, {C[1] -> 0}} *)
```

Minimum `r` is thus seen to be 0 if we are only restricting it to nonnegative values. Or, if we want it to be strictly positive,

```
Minimize[{3 C[1], C[1] > 0}, C[1], Integers]
(* -> {3, {C[1] -> 1}} *)
```

Minimum `r` is 3.

Note that `Reduce` and `Minimize` are limited in their capabilities, and therefore it may not be possible to use this approach in more difficult cases.

Comment: What does C[1] mean in the first output? The documentation says "C[1] is the default form for the first parameter or constant generated in representing the results of various symbolic computations. " So what is the first parameter? What's the default form?

Comment: @LoveRight `C[1]` is *Mathematica*'s way of writing an arbitrary constant. Here `Reduce` tells us that `C[1]` is any nonnegative integer. Then, we proceed to ask `Minimize` for a specific value of `C[1]` that minimizes `r`.

Comment: If there is a solution, it is periodic modulo `EulerPhi[37]`. Here's a solution that does not need `Minimize`: `Min[r /. Solve[Mod[10^r - 1, 37] == 0 && 0 < r <= EulerPhi[37], r, Integers]]`.

Answer (score 11):

Find the first positive integer that satisfies the condition:

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, ! Element[(10^# - 1)/37, Integers] &]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Or

```
r = 0; NestWhile[Element[(10^(++r) - 1)/37, Integers] &, False, Not]; r
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Or

```
Block[{r = 1},
  While[! Element[(10^r++ - 1)/37, Integers]];
  r - 1]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Comment: This solution uses traditional while loops and works. It doesn't use math knowledge and is much slower than Oleksandr R.'s solution. But the style of writing a loop is worth learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You are asking for a solution to the equation $10^r\equiv 1$, mod $n$, where in your particular case $n=37$. The multiplicative order is the smallest exponent $r$ such that $x^r\equiv 1$, mod $n$. The multiplicative order is given by the Mathematica command MultiplicativeOrder[x,n], and corresponds to the "Foo" you asked for in your comment to @mgamer. Hence, the solution is

```
MultiplicativeOrder[10,37]
(* 3 *)
```

The speed of this single command is at least 100 times faster than any other previously posted solution. For $n=739523387$ the result $r=369761693$ is returned in 0.00004 s on my machine.

Comment: I ignored this question at first because I thought, there's a built-in command for such a fundamental equation and someone must have already found it. (+1 of course.)

Comment: So _that's_ how `Reduce` is doing it.  This is now, by far, the best answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a brute-force approach on larger and larger powers of ten, this constructs the multiplier digit by digit by dividing from the bottom up.  There is only one choice for each digit.  This is much faster than the brute-force approach when the number of digits is large.

```
nines[n_ /; n > 2 && OddQ[n] && ! Divisible[n, 5]] :=
 Block[{x, r = 0, k = 1},
  x = Ordering[Mod[n Range[0, 9], 10]] - 1;
  While[r = Quotient[r + n x[[10 - Mod[r, 10]]], 10]; r != 0, k++];
  k
 ]

nines[37]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
nines[19]
```

> ```
> 18
> ```

```
nines[343]
```

> ```
> 294
> ```

```
Divisible[10^294 - 1, 343]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Timing[nines[582749]]
```

> ```
> {0.975075, 276030}
> ```

```
Timing[NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, ! Divisible[10^# - 1, 582749] &]]
```

> ```
> {219.193427, 276030}
> ```

```
Divisible[10^276030 - 1, 582749]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

While that was satisfying, a brute-force approach with `PowerMod` turns out to be faster, which also avoids working directly with giant powers of ten.  (Inspired by Chip Hurst's answer.)

```
Timing[NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, PowerMod[10, #, 582749] != 1 &]]
```

> ```
> {0.485487, 276030}
> ```

This could be combined with Chip Hurst's answer, where that approach is used when `n` has a primitive root (which is faster still), or this brute force with `PowerMod` is used when it does not.

Going back to the direct solution, that should be blindingly fast in C, since it works on machine integers.  However I could not get `Compile[]` to generate efficient code for this for some reason.  So here is the algorithm using `CompileLibrary[]` with the C code written manually:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

nineslib = CreateLibrary["#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
   DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
   }
   DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return 0;
   }
   DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
   }
   DLLEXPORT int nines(WolframLibraryData libData,
            mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
       int k, x[10];
       mint n, p, r = 0;
       n = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
       if (n > 2 && (n & 1) && n % 5) {
           for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)
               x[9 - (n * k) % 10] = k;
           p = 0;
           do {
               p = (p + n * x[p % 10]) / 10;
               r++;
           } while (p);
       }
       MArgument_setInteger(Res, r);
       return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
   }", "nines"];

ninesc = LibraryFunctionLoad[nineslib, "nines", {Integer}, Integer];
```

Trying it out:

```
ninesc[343]
```

> ```
> 294
> ```

```
Timing[ninesc[582749]]
```

> ```
> {0.002242, 276030}
> ```

Yep, blindingly fast.  And it seems to be quite a bit faster than the primitive root approach, where there is a primitive root.

```
Timing[ninesc[739523387]]
```

> ```
> {3.050735, 369761693}
> ```

```
Timing[MinExponent[{10, 1, 739523387}, r]]
```

> ```
> Solving Mod[224945292 r,369761693]==0
>
> {100.140380, r == 369761693}
> ```

Comment: This solution involves much more advanced methods. I really need to take some time to learn it, especially the inter-operation with other language. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it's really simple.  37 times q gives a sequence of 9's.  What would you multiply 7 by to get a 9 in the last digit?  7x7 = 49.  So the last digit of q is 7.  7x37 = 259.  The next digit in q times 7 plus the 5 in 259 has to give the next 9.  So what times 7 ends in a 4?  7x2 = 14.  2x37 = 74.  25+74=99.  So for q=27, we have 999.  Done!  (If we didn't get a 9 in the third digit, then we would just keep going, picking one more digit of the multiplier to give another 9 in that digit of the product.  Until we have all 9's.)

Comment: The solution using `MultiplicativeOrder` is the one using "more advanced methods".  It is much faster than my constructive approach.  Which was already pretty fast.

Answer (score 5):

From $(10^r-1)/37=n$ it follows $10^r=37n+1$ The first $n$ such that $37n+1$ is a power of 10 is 27, since $37*27+1=1000$. So $(10^3-1)/37=3$. So r=3

Comment: Yes. This process is clear. But I'm seeking a Mathematica command to do this. For example Foo[Element[(10^r - 1)/37, Integers], r, r$\in$Integers]. What is the Foo?

Answer (score 5):

We can reduce your problem to solving a linear equation modulo an integer. That way we can avoid functions like `Minimize`.

If a primitive root exists for the modulus, we can take discrete logarithms of both sides and easily solve for `r`. This following code finds the smallest positive `r` such that `(b^r - c)/mod ∈ Integers`.

```
HasPrimitiveRootQ[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  n < 8 || (OddQ[n] && PrimePowerQ[n]) || (OddQ[n/2] && PrimePowerQ[n/2])
HasPrimitiveRootQ[_] = False;

MinExponent[{b_, c_, mod_?HasPrimitiveRootQ}, r_] := Module[{g,dlhs,drhs,phi,gcd,sol},
    g = PrimitiveRoot[mod];
    dlhs = MultiplicativeOrder[g, mod, {b}];
    drhs = MultiplicativeOrder[g, mod, {c}];
    phi = EulerPhi[mod];
    gcd = GCD[dlhs, drhs, phi];

    {dlhs, drhs, phi} /= gcd;

    Print["Solving ", Mod[dlhs r, phi] == Mod[drhs, phi]];

    r == Mod[drhs*PowerMod[dlhs, -1, phi], phi, 1]
]
```

And your example reduces to solving a linear equation mod 3:

```
MinExponent[{10, 1, 37}, r]
```

> `Solving Mod[2r, 3] == 0`
>
> ```
> r == 3
> ```

Comment: Very nice (and mention upvote so this has enough characters).

Comment: Doesn't always work.  `HasPrimitiveRootQ[582749]` returns `False`, but 582749 has a solution.  (See my answer.)

Comment: @MarkAdler right, which is why I have the disclaimer `"If a primitive root exists for the modulus"`.

Comment: Though it gave me an idea for a better approach ...

Answer (score 4):

Because the domain is described as `Integers`, and because negative integers cannot satisfy the condition, the first **non negative** integer that satisfy the condition is **0**, as the following expression can prove if necessary.

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 0, ! IntegerQ[(10^# - 1)/37] &]
(* 0 *)
```

If the domain is instead **positive** `Integers`, a sligtly modification is enough:

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, ! IntegerQ[(10^# - 1)/37] &]
(* 3 *)
```

An easy to read command that find the first integers satisfying the condition, and the first of them, is:

```
Position[Range[100], r_ /; IntegerQ[(10^r - 1)/37]] // Flatten
First@%
```

Result:

```
{3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, \
57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99}

3
```

A minor modification for Mathematica 10 is:

```
FirstPosition[Range[100], r_ /; IntegerQ[(10^r - 1)/37]] // First
```

Both last expressions require a guess of how many integers we have to test before finding an integer satisfying the condition, this is the meaning of `Range[100]`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple brute force :

```
r = 1;
While[Not@IntegerQ[(10^r - 1)/37], r++]
r
```

returns 3.